# How to sort glob.glob numerically?

Tags: python, list, sorting, glob

I have a bunch of files sorted numerically on a folder, when I try to sort glob.glob I never get the files in the right order.

---

**file examples and expected output sorting**

```
folder
------
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\1 sample.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\2 sample.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\3 sample.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\4 sample.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\5 sample.mp3
... over 800 files...
```

---

**What I tried** but the output seems random

```py
files = sorted(glob.glob(f'{os.getcwd()}/*.mp3'), key=lambda x: (os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0]))


C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\1 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\10 speech.mp3 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\100 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\101 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\102 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\103 speech.mp3  
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\104 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\105 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\106 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\107 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\108 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\109 speech.mp3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\11 speech.mp3
```

Is not a solution try to sorting by date or size.

**UPDATE**
all the previous answer worked great:

```py
l = sorted(glob.glob(f'{os.getcwd()}/*.mp3'), key=len)
l = sorted(glob.glob(f'{os.getcwd()}/*.mp3'), key=lambda x: int(os.path.basename(x).split(' ')[0]))

def get_key(fp):
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fp))[0]
    int_part = filename.split()[0]
    return int(int_part)

l = sorted(glob.glob(f'{os.getcwd()}/*.mp3'), key=get_key)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer would catch the number with `re.match()` and to convert that number (string) to integer with `int()`. Use these numbers to sort the files with `sorted()`

### Code

```py
import re 
import math
from pathlib import Path 

file_pattern = re.compile(r'.*?(\d+).*?')
def get_order(file):
    match = file_pattern.match(Path(file).name)
    if not match:
        return math.inf
    return int(match.groups()[0])

sorted_files = sorted(files, key=get_order)
```

#### Example input

Consider random files with ***one* integer** number in **any part of the filename**:

```
├── 012 some file.mp3
├── 1 file.txt
├── 13 file.mp3
├── 2 another file.txt
├── 3 file.csv
├── 4 file.mp3
├── 6 yet another file.txt
├── 88 name of file.mp3
├── and final 999.txt
├── and some another file7.txt
├── some 5 file.mp3
└── test.py
```

#### Example output

The `get_order()` could be used to sort the files, when passed to the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin function in the `key` argument

```py
In [1]: sorted(files, key=get_order)
Out[1]:
['C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\1 file.txt',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\2 another file.txt',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\3 file.csv',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\4 file.mp3',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\some 5 file.mp3',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\6 yet another file.txt',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\and some another file7.txt',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\012 some file.mp3',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\13 file.mp3',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\88 name of file.mp3',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\and final 999.txt',
 'C:\\tmp\\file_sort\\test.py']
```

#### Short explanation

- The [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) is used to give a small speed boost (if matching multiple times same pattern)
- The [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) is used to match the regular expression patterh
- In the regex pattern, `.*?` means any character (`.`), zero or more times (`*`) non-greedily (`?`). `\d+` matches any digit number one or more times, and the parenthesis just captures that match to the `groups()` list.
- In case of no match (no digits in the file), the `match` will be `None`, and the `get_order` gives infinity; these files are sorted arbitrarily, but one could add logic for these (was not asked in this question).
- The `sorted()` function takes `key` argument, which should be callable which takes one argument: The item in the list. In this case, it will be one of those file strings (full file path)
- The `Path(file).name` just takes the filename part (without suffix) from full file path.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import glob
import os
files = sorted(glob.glob(f'{os.getcwd()}/*.txt'), key=len)
print(files)
```

Comment: This work great, could you explain why is working correctly with len?

Comment: Because ```C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\10 speech.mp3``` is longer then ```C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\1 speech.mp3``` and it will sort the same lengthed ones.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. Length of path/11.mp3. would be the same of path/10.mp3. For the key you should rather use a lamba function as in the Jonas answer. Check examples also in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2114348

In my case I didn't use os.getcwd but used a variable for my images_path, exameple: `files = sorted(glob.glob(f'{images_path}/*.{extension}'), key=lambda a: int(a.replace(images_path + '/', '').replace(f'.{extension}', '')))` not super elefant to do 2 replacements as I did, but it's very readable and easy to understand, so I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are splitting the full path, not the basename. You can try this:

```
files = sorted(glob.glob(f'{os.getcwd()}/*.mp3'), key=lambda x: int(os.path.basename(x).split(' ')[0]))
```

Comment: this will give me the same what I display in the updated question

Comment: maybe you have to convert it to int(): key=lambda x: int(os.path.basename(x).split(' ')[0]))

Comment: Yes, my bad. All the previous answers worked, but this was the most similar to what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```py
import os, glob

def get_key(fp):
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fp))[0]
    int_part = filename.split()[0]
    return int(int_part)

files = sorted(glob.glob(f'{os.getcwd()}/*.mp3'), key=get_key)
```